# Whats the problem with my ball pepper plants?

Tags: bell-peppers

Good day,

I have quite a few ball pepper plants having the same issue. Is it because of the low winter temperatures (around 10C), or is there another issue? If so, what do I do to control it?

[image: Leaf1]

[image: Plant1]

[image: Plant2]

[image: Leaf2]

Thanks

Comment: Is it growing in a container?

Comment: No, it’s on the ground. I have a few in containers too and they are looking similar.